# Cleanup Perl code: my $export = $doc; $export =~ s:\.odt:\.pdf:;

Tags: regex, perl, code-cleanup

Perl code fragment:

```
my $export = $doc;
$export =~ s:\.odt:\.pdf:;
```

How would this be written cleaner? Not simply what are 900 other ways to write it, [TMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
my ($export = $doc) =~ s{\.odt}{\.pdf};
```

**UPDATE:** That solution doesn't compile (note to self: test before posting on SO). Instead you could say

```
(my $export = $doc) =~ s{\.odt}{\.pdf};
```

Answer (score 7):

I go for `[.]` to match a literal period:

```
$export ~= s{[.]odt$}{.pdf};
```

Note that only the first half of the `s///` call is a regular expression.  The replacement is a normal string, and does not require a period to be escaped.

You might want to represent files as objects and not strings, though, with [Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Path::Class).

Comment: I think you mean \z, not $.  $ is only rarely desirable.

Comment: +1 for the separator {} being a little easier for me to read than : and the removal of the escape sequence in the replacement string.

Comment: `\z` is the "I am a PBP fanboi" escape sequence.

Answer (score 0):

my %ext = ( 'odt' => 'pdf', etc... );
(my $export = $doc) =~ s{.([^.]+)$}{'.'.($ext{$1}||$1})}eg;