# Perl compile error on: "my ($export = $doc) =~ s{\.odt}{\.pdf};"

Tags: perl

Based upon SO answer "[my ($export = $doc) =~ s{.odt}{.pdf};](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954432/cleanup-perl-code-my-export-doc-export-s-odt-pdf/2954484#2954484)" why does this Perl script produce a compile error?

```
$ cat so.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $doc ="x.odt";
my ($export = $doc) =~ s{\.odt}{.pdf};
$ ./so.pl
Can't declare scalar assignment in "my" at ./so.pl line 3, near ") =~"
Execution of ./so.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: Because I didn't test my code before I submitted it to SO :-(  Sorry.    Try  `(my $export = $doc) =~ ...`

Comment: @mobrule... what's that "test" thing you speaketh of?

Comment: @DVK. I've only heard rumors, but my understanding is that it is an arcane and powerful spell discovered by 11th century Alchemists, and rediscovered by Python programmers in 2007. Black magic, really.

Comment: @mobrule,@C.W.Holeman - and now I have this visage of Randal Schwartz in Spartan garb with a sword yelling "THIS... IS... PERL!!!", after being asked a particularly annoying question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the **my** inside of the parenthesis...

```
(my $export = $doc) =~ s{\.odt}{.pdf};
```